# Why does 'selector' return value differ from 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Inside an event handler, why does $(this) return something else than $('.selector')?

Example:

```
$('.container').click(function () {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($('.container'));
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/upVcm/2/)

When you look in the console the results are different.

Comment: Are you asking why the two console.log results aren't identical?

Comment: Yes i am. The two answers are helpful!

Comment: Interesting detail: your question says "$('#Selector')" but your code says "$('.Selector')". In a normal situation, the id selector probably **will** be the same as `$(this)` because an id is supposed to be unique, so a single element will be selected.

Comment: Edited my question ;). That is a good thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is always the element on which the event **originated**, in other words which of the `.container` elements you clicked exactly.

e.g.:

```
<div class="container">container1</div>
<span class="container">container2</span>
```

as Jonathan Lonowski notes, `$(".container")` selects both `.container` elements but `this` is the one you clicked, either the `span` or the `div`.

Also, `$(this)` just wraps that element into a JQuery object, the `this` keyword itself is native javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Inside the of the event handler, `this` will normally refer to the **single** `.container` element that captured the event.

While the selector will once again find all of the `.container`s throughout the document.